# Uploaded image using php doesn't fully work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The problem is this one:

I have a code that uploads a picture to phpmyadmin, the code... doesn't fully work for some reason, it doesn't upload the image fully and the image ends up having a very small size, and it won't show up either. If I upload them directly to the database, they can be shown, but the ones uploaded using the code below have that problem.

This is the code I have:

**Code for the button:**

```
   <div id="content">
<form method="POST" action =""/>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
        Upload a picture
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="file" name="image"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrarme"/> <input type="reset"/> 

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  require("iniciar.php");
    }
 ?>
</div>
```

**Code for the uploading:** (iniciar.php)

```
<?php
$image = $_POST['image'];
$reqlen = strlen($image);
if($reqlen > 0){
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','image');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', '$image', '')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo 'Upload successful';
}else{
echo 'Please insert an image';  
}
?>
```

This is the structure of the table:
[The table I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACgay.png)

Comment: Aside from the issue you're having, MySQL is the database, phpmyadmin is an admin panel for that database. You're uploading images to mysql, not phpadmin. Also, unless you have a great reason to do so, don't upload images directly into the database, upload them to a file and store the filepath in the database.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This code can't possibly work, it doesn't access the [file data](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) at all.

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning like input data instead of

```
            $_FILES["image"]["name"];

         //remove thisline
    $image=$_POST['evidence'];
// you have to use it like this

     $image=   $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

you have to assign image like this

```
$target_file =  $target_dir . '/' . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$image=$target_file;
```

now evidence hold address of image so dir. of image is now on evidence too.now it will be uploaded to data base you aren't passing data. that's the mistake. any questions comment .if it solves your problem mark it as solved :)

for reference ,this is the php script used to upload profile picture,

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    {
        $target_dir = "profilepic/";
        $targetfile=$target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($targetfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if($imageFileType != "jpg" &&$imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "GIF" ) 
        {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;

        }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
        {
        echo "<small>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</small>";
        }
         else 
         {
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetfile)) 
         {
           echo "<small>upload successful</small>";
           $imgdir="UPDATE user SET profilepic='$targetfile' WHERE username='$uname';";
           $con->query($imgdir);
           header("location:profile.php");

         }
         else
          echo "not uploaded";
         } 
    }
?>
```

**make changes according to your data base & operations.**